# NullReferenceException when executing pathAnalyzer/newMapAgent

Tags: configuration, path-analyzer

I'm a new maintainer for an instance of Sitecore 8.2. I'm seeing this error *a lot* in the logs:

```
1664 16:28:00 WARN  Could not find constructor in ReflectionUtil.CreateObject: Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.Remote.RemoteWebRequestFactory. The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class. Parameter info: Count: 2. Parameter types: Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Configuration, System.String
1664 16:28:00 FATAL [Path Analyzer](ApplicationContainer.GetInstance) Can't create instance using path 'pathAnalyzer/webRequestFactory'. Make sure the referred element is present in configuration
1664 16:28:00 ERROR Exception when executing agent pathAnalyzer/newMapAgent
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.PathAnalyzer
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.Remote.RemoteTreeDefinitionService.BuildRequest(String requestPath, HttpMethod requestMethod, Byte[] requestData)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.Remote.RemoteTreeDefinitionService.GetAllDefinitions()
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.NewMapAgent.GetTreeDefinitions()
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.BuildMapAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

It seems to be coming from this snippet in Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.RemoteClient.config:

```
<webRequestFactory type="Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Data.Remote.RemoteWebRequestFactory, Sitecore.PathAnalyzer">
  <param desc="configuration" ref="pathAnalyzer/configuration" />
  <param desc="httpTransportFactory" ref="httpTransportFactory" />
</webRequestFactory>
```

I'm pretty new to Sitecore and I'm having trouble finding anything about this particular issue. **How should I fix this?**

Comment: This basically comes down to an ordering of processors. This is explained in detail [here](https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2016/08/28/fixing-path-analyzer-fatal-error-cannot-create-instance-using-path/)

Comment: @ChrisBartlett I've already checked that article and that solution was already implemented, so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Do you think I should incorporate that into the question?

Comment: @ChrisBartlett The first comment on that article suggests it's not even an issue anymore in 8.2. Maybe the fix is now causing the issue? I'll have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this may depend on the role of your server.  Do you have a distributed Sitecore install (CM + CD servers as separate roles)?  Because if this is a single instance server, you should delete that config file.

You'll want to reference the config file Enable Disable spreadsheet (https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/server_configuration_resources).